# No Module named WhiteNoise

Tags: django, heroku

```
2022-08-05T17:47:45.758949+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 
'whitenoise'
2022-08-05T17:47:45.759055+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-08-05 17:47:45 +0000] [10] [INFO] 
Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2022-08-05T17:47:45.817101+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-08-05 17:47:45 +0000] [11] [ERROR] 
Exception in worker process
```

""hello, I am getting this error while uploading my Django to the heroku"""

```
   STATIC_URL = 'static/'
   STATICFILES_DIRS=[(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'))]
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

   MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
   MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

   FILE_URL = '/file/'
   FILE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'file/')
```

here is my requirements.txt

```
asgiref==3.5.2
backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
Django==4.1
gunicorn==20.1.0
Pillow==9.2.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
tzdata==2022.1
whitenoise==6.2.0
```

Comment: Do you expect `whitenoise` to be present on Heroku? Why? Have you declared it as a dependency, e.g. by including it in your `requirements.txt` or `Pipfile`?

Comment: yes, I added it to my requirements.txt

Comment: Do you also have `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` files?